# Cookie is "undefined" in Koa/Express request

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, cookies, koa

I'm using Koa JS framework for jwt authentication.

So basically when the user signs in, I set a jwt token (signed) to user's browser cookie, which seems to work fine as shown below (Chrome cookie settings):

[image]

(www.localhost.com instead of localhost is because I edited my hostfile, but this should have no effect in setting/getting cookies)

The problem, however, is when I send a POST request to my local Koa server, the jwt cookie is undefined. All I'm doing to verify the token is this:

## routes.js

```
const Router = require("koa-router");

const router = new Router();
router.post(`api/authenticate`, function* () {
    const jwt = this.cookies.get("jwt", { signed: true });   //jwt is undefined!!
    if (!jwt)
        this.throw("Invalid or expired token!");

    this.status = 200;
});
//...
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());
```

Here, **this.cookies.get("jwt")** returns undefined. The POST request is sent using AXIOS library with "withCredentials: true" header and a valid CSRF token:

## authenticate.js

```
axios.post("api/authenticate", {}, {
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "X-CSRF-Token": "A VALID CSRF TOKEN GENERATED BY SERVER",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

Can anyone help me find out why **this.cookies.get** fails to fetch cookie from a simple POST request? I'm simply posting to my localhost, so I believe this is not a CORS problem.

What is more strange is that when I check my chrome developer tool, the "jwt" and "jwt.sig" tokens are successfully included in the request header..

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

## Update: Setting the cookie

```
//...
this.cookies.set("jwt", "SOME JWT GENERATED BY SERVER", {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    signed: true,
                });
//...
```

Comment: `if !(jwt)` or `if (!jwt)`?

Comment: @Vohuman Thanks for catching that but that was just a typo. When I debug my node js server, "jwt" is "undefined" in my debugger

Comment: Do you have `cookie-parser` middleware enabled in your application? Specifically, before your router? Something like `app.use(cookieParser())`.

Comment: @roflmyeggo according to Koa official documentation, it seems like cookieParser is not needed like in Express.. https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/context.md

Comment: Can you show how you are setting the cookie? Also does it work with without the `signed` option?

Comment: @roflmyeggo Updated answer. Removing the signed option didn't help.. Still undefined cookie. Thanks for taking time to look into this :) I have been trying to fix this for 3 hours but still no luck

Comment: Might be related to an improper SHA1 value in the `jwt.sig` cookie. If it is signed with the wrong key then undefined will always be returned. Try creating it without signing it and then getting it without the signed option.

Comment: @roflmyeggo Thanks but removing "signed: true" from both setting and getting cookies did not work :(  I really have no idea where it went wrong

Comment: Try using another browser besides Chrome.

Comment: if you hook in outside of koa context, directly in raw node (in the request, run console.log(this.req.headers.cookie) ), can you see any cookies ?

Comment: I know that this question is a little bit old, but I'm struggling with the same problem. Cookie created in browser from server, cookie sent to server in request, but ctx.cookies.get("name") returns undefined.

Any updates?